# Do we need a smallsat tag, or might we just include small satellites within the cubesat tag's usage guidance?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

To [What was the first satellite with COTS electronics?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49800/12102) I've added the [cubesat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubesat) tag though I really just want to specify any small satellites (as opposed to space stations and big communications satellites)

**Questions:**

1. Does anyone think we need a `smallsat` tag for these?
2. If not, should we update the usage guidance for the [cubesat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cubesat) tag to allow for smallsats, or is that counterproductive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently removed the poorly conceived tag [small](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small) from a question because I wasn't sure if they meant for it to refer to smallsats or small rockets, but it did cross my mind that it might be useful to have a [smallsat](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smallsat) tag. Something as a catch-all so that we don't have to create tags for all the individual categories aside from cubesats unless we actually need to.

Comment: I just ran across the existence of a [smallsat symposium](https://2021.smallsatshow.com/) and [smallsat.org](https://smallsat.org/) and noticed that at least a few spacecraft engineering companies have smallsat divisions, so it does seem like reasonably well scoped class that is not covered by cubesat. I'll go ahead and apply it to the question in question and a few more.